# Facebook application new settings. Bookmark URL issue

Tags: facebook, url, settings, bookmarks

I need to ask where can I set up Bookmark URL for my new application right now?

There was few changes few days ago and it is impossible to put it anywhere. Because of that, I can't set sending invitations to the FanPage TAB with application, it's always redirecting invited users to the canvas.

Maybe somebody know how to do it right now?

Answer (score 0):

It has disappeared from the updated App Settings dashboard.

What you can do is set up your canvas URL (I'm assuming you're only using this application for the Page tab) to redirect to the Page tab URL.

The contents of your canvas URL would look something like this:

```
"http://www.facebook.com/PAGENAME?sk=app_1234567890"
```

Comment: Hm.. what i really need is to make application (let's say a form) with the "invite" button. I will add this application to my fanpage as a tab. When users click "invite" button i want their friend to be redirect to the FANPAGE TAB WITH FORM, not the CANVAS WITH FORM.

Comment: Facebook has mentioned that they're restoring the Bookmark URL for 90 days: http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/547/ 

My answer above still applies to your problem. When invitations appear on the notification, it links directly to your default canvas URL. From that URL, redirect your users to your Fan Page Tab using the code example above.